# Android - Java drawing coordinates on multiple screens

Tags: java, android, server, drawing, screen

I'm making a game like "Draw My Thing".

Now, in this game of course, a server is required, for which every person can see what the other player is drawing.

I managed to paint from one screen to another, but the problem is that the coordinates of the drawings are not the same if the dimension (WIDTH AND HEIGHT) of the screen is different.

Here's some code to begin with:

**PAINT COMPONENT**

```
public class DRAW_AREA extends JComponent {

// Image in which we're going to draw
private Image image;
private Graphics2D g2;
private int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;
private int WIDTH, HEIGHT;

private ServerSocket SERVER;
private Socket CLIENT;
private BufferedReader INPUT;
private PrintWriter OUTPUT;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                if (image == null) {
                    image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
                    g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
                    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                    clear();
                }
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }

public void clear() {
        g2.setPaint(Color.white);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(6));
        g2.setPaint(Color.black);
        repaint();
    }
```

**Server**

**NOTE:**

oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY are values sent from the client

```
if (g2 != null) {
                                g2.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
                                repaint();
                                oldX = currentX;
                                oldY = currentY;
                            }
```

Comment: Map the old coordinates to the new ones using a percentage of their relative displacement to the screen width/height

Comment: Either do what Kon has mentioned above and scale the coordinates, or set window size in which the user can draw in so other screens will also be the same size.

Comment: @Kon You lost me. Can you give me an example? I'm not so familiar with paint classes and proportion of screens.

Comment: @ZaidQureshi It has to be the user's default screen size.

Comment: what do you mean default screen, if the painter has the screen size 300x300 make sure watchers screen size is also 300x300, but if you just want to scale it you take `originWidth/localWidth` would give you the ratio that you would multiply with the xCoordinate to scale it. You would do similar for y coordinate but with height instead.

Comment: @ZaidQureshi I tried your suggestion, but it didn't worked, since ".drawLine" is requesting an int, instead of float.

Comment: @Alahlavo then cast it to an int

Comment: You are going to need to use double to keep the decimals as they do represent a ratio, as in int, anything less than 1 will be shown as 0. So if the ratio is 95% i.e 0.95 cast your coordinate after multiply back to integer.